# Filter objects using preference activity

Tags: android, filter, android-preferences

I have a preference activity on my app where I select from a list of preferences. After selecting my practice I want to use that selected value to filter my data by practice on a fragment. I am able to get the value I selected on the settings screen but it is just not filtering.

This is what I have so far:

PreferenceActivity:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        entries = new ArrayList<>();
        entryValues = new ArrayList<>();
        practicesListPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference("my_practice_setting");

        populatePracticeListPreference();

        SharedPreferences sp = getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences();
        sp.edit().putString(KEY_PREF_MY_PRACTICE_ID, JsonDataParser
                .practiceNameAndIdMap.get(sp.getString(KEY_PREF_MY_PRACTICE, ""))).apply();
        String s = sp.getString(KEY_PREF_MY_PRACTICE_ID,"NONE");

        practicesListPreference.setSummary(sp.getString(KEY_PREF_MY_PRACTICE, "All"));

        int storedPreference = sp.getInt("storedInt", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putInt("storedInt", storedPreference); // value to store
        editor.commit();
    }
```

and this is the fragment I'm using to filter:

```
 practiceSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());

            String pid=sharedPreferences.getString(PreferencesActivity.KEY_PREF_MY_PRACTICE,"");
                if(practiceSpinnerAdapter.isEmpty()){
                    practiceSpinnerAdapter.add("All");
                }

                pid = practiceSpinnerAdapter.getItem(i);
                mAdapter.clear();
                mAdapter.addAll(filterAssetsList(pid));
```

and my filter method inside the fragment:

```
   private List<Asset> filterAssetsList(String filterString){
    List<Asset> filteredAssets = new ArrayList<>();
    if(JsonDataParser.assetsList!=null){
        if(filterString.equals("All")){
           return JsonDataParser.assetsList;
        }
        for (Asset asset: JsonDataParser.assetsList ) {
           // String s= asset.getPracticeID();
            if(asset.getPracticeID().equals(filterString)){
                filteredAssets.add(asset);
            }
        }
    }
    return filteredAssets;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to add return statement on end of filterAssetsList method

Comment: I did that,still not working

Comment: so i assume you did debug step-by-step your `filterAssetsList` method? what does `getPracticeID` return?

Comment: yes and its getting the correct filtered items but not displaying them

Comment: called `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: thank you so much, its working now. I used mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()